# CSV to JSON in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, csv

I am trying to convert CSV to JSON in angularjs, but I am unable to.

Here is the raw data, I receive from API -

`"sentby: Sanjay, sitename: Flipkart, PinCode: 080, stdnumber: 56477382, website: https://flipkart.com, status: Done".`

I want to convert this to JSON

Comment: is this a string you get or object literals?

Comment: Yes it a object literals

Comment: @ManishMallavarapu yes I am splitting the string now, but later I realized that ng-model won't work, I am using comma delimiter

Comment: `let res = {};str.split(', ').forEach(s=>{let t = s.split(': '); res[t[0]] = t[1];});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could convert a csv string into an object with something like this

```
var csv = "sentby: Sanjay, sitename: Flipkart, PinCode: 080, stdnumber: 56477382, website: https://flipkart.com, status: Done";
console.log(csv
    .split(',')
    .reduce(function (obj, field) {
        var parts = field.split(':');
        obj[parts[0].trim()] = parts[1].trim();
        return obj;
    }, {}));
```

Comment: This answer could probably be improved by explaining why it works. Not everyone understands how reduce and similar methods of the Array object work.

Comment: This works for the given example, but not all CSVs. The allowance for escaped commas makes it trickier.