# angular js csv string to json array

Tags: javascript, json, csv

I have some comma-separated data;

```
"HotelName","Remained","Date"
"Maxx","4","Jun 26 2016"
"Voyage","3","Jun 24 2016"
```

I need to convert this to a json array like below. How can I do that in my javascript code?

```
[
  {
    HotelName:"Maxx",
    Remained:"4",
    Date:"Jun 26 2016"
  },
  {
    HotelName:"Voyage",
    Remained:"3",
    Date:"Jun 24 2016"
  }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you researched your question before asking?

Comment: up to now, I've tried different combinations of angularjs methods like angular.fromJson, JSON.parse, JSON.stringify etc.

Comment: http://techslides.com/convert-csv-to-json-in-javascript took me two seconds to google.

Comment: impressed by your googling skills good for you, I have seen this, it adds extra quote marks and mismatches label-value pairs, since my data is with quotes, not in csv format

Comment: What is you data format ? (String ?)

Comment: the thing is, It comes from an external server as string with double quotes in it as I give in the first part

Comment: [see also this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493195/how-can-i-parse-a-csv-string-with-javascript-which-contains-comma-in-data)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSV to JSON in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37351517/csv-to-json-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

Ceeate an array `var data = new Array()`, push data in it like so `data.push({ item : value})` and then convert like so `data_json = JSON.stringify(data)`. I use that for my angularprojects.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a String, maybe you could split it.

```
var lines data.split('\n');
var array = [];
if(lines.length > 0){
    var titles = lines[0].split(',');
    for(var i=1; i<lines.length; ++i){
        var obj = lines[i].split(',');
        var newItem = {};
        //you should check that titles and obj are of same length
        for(var j=0, j<titles.length; ++j){
            newItem[titles[j]] = obj[j];
        }
        array.push(newItem);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the response which comes from the remote server is a stringified JSON data.

```
// Possible a CSV data string from your server;
var csvData = "\"HotelName\",\"Remained\",\"Date\"\"Maxx\",\"4\",\"Jun 26 2016\",\"Voyage\",\"3\",\"Jun 24 2016\"";

var NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 3;
var columns = [];
var arrayData = [];

// Remove double quotations in csvData and convert it to the array;
csvData = csvData.replace(/"/g, "").split(',');
columns = csvData.slice(0, NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS);
csvData = csvData.slice(NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS);

var rowObject = {};
csvData.forEach(function(item, index) {
  rowObject[columns[index % (NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS)]] = item;
  if (index % (NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS) == 2) {
    arrayData.push(rowObject);
    rowObject = {};
  }
})

console.log(arrayData);
/*
  [ 
    {
      DataMaxx: "Voyage",
      HotelName: "4",
      Remained: "Jun 26 2016"
    }
  ]
*/
```